Conditions on Signed distance function and the norm of the gradient
Given a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and its signed distance function $\phi$ (negative inside the curve, zero on the curve, and positive outside the curve), we know that $\phi$ is differentiable almost everywhere, and wherever it is differentiable, we have $\Vert \nabla \phi \Vert = 1$.
The converse is not necessarily true. For instance, say along a specific outward normal direction, if the directional derivative alternates many times between 1 and -1 (so the cross-section of the graph of the function looks like a w shape (or maybe with even more turns) instead of a simple v shape), the condition above will still be satisfied, but the function is no longer a signed distance function. (Sorry for such a wordy description, I'm pretty sure that this can be described mathematically in a more concise way, but I couldn't think of it.)
So here is my question. Given a continuous function $\phi$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which

has a function value of zero on a closed curve, a positive function value outside the curve, and a negative function value inside the curve,
is differentiable almost everywhere, and $\Vert \nabla \phi \Vert = 1$ wherever differentiable.

With what additional conditions, we can guarantee that $\phi$ is indeed the signed distance function of its zero level set?
